# Fixing "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, maps

I've included two below scripts in my header and I get the error *"You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors."*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js key=************"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

When I remove either script, I get additional js errors. How can I properly refactor these two scripts in my rails app?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your example above, you're including the same script twice, but with different parameters. You should be able to solve your issue by including the script once, with all the required parameters like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: @Jackson A good place to start is to review the docs, which usually shows you how parameters are organized. If you're newer to web dev, read a bit about url parameters, something like this will get you started http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Answer (score 13):

If you're calling google maps via an ajax call, you can use `window.google = {}` upon exiting the state in which the map was called.

Comment: I am working on a Vue SPA and when I hit a component with a map, then leave and come back, I would get this message, so in the component, I added a `destroy()` function (not under methods, it's a component-level method) and did `$('#google-map').remove()` and `window.google = {}`, the combination of which eliminated this message.

Comment: This is great. Working too on framework7, using template on pageBeforeRemoval

Comment: can you explain this solution a bit more?

Answer (score 8):

I know that in my case it's not a Rails app but might help to someone else ... I'm working with React and I was getting the same error when I was switching between views/pages.

And like wLc said `window.google = {}` worked like a charm and was deleting the error in the console but the `<script>` tag was remaining in the html and was added every time I was revisiting the page that has the map.

On `componentWillUnmount` I've added some code to remove the tag.

```
const allScripts = document.getElementsByTagName( 'script' );
[].filter.call(
  allScripts, 
  ( scpt ) => scpt.src.indexOf( 'key=googleAPIKEY' ) >= 0
 )[ 0 ].remove();

 window.google = {};
```

Comment: Amazing. Would never guess. I'm popping up php file using jquery to show the location. That file has google maps api with a key.  This, `window.google = {}` placed in `$(document).ready(function() {... }` totally solved the problem.