# "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page" Error

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following in my html page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script 
        async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=hUnDAdjYG_Wz7u2qL6unHqfBOmvaZ0H1Mg&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

First link is for Google's API Geometry Library , and the second initialises and draws the map.

I'm getting the error "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors."

I know that this can be fixed by calling just one script, and changing the parameters, see [Fixing "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930274/fixing-you-have-included-the-google-maps-api-multiple-times-on-this-page-this) I don't know how to replicate the answer for my problem though.

Comment: I have the same issue in my MVC application and I am trying to open a  bootstrap modal with the map. I don't really know where to put the google maps script to avoid the "multiple imports" issue. Anyone?

Comment: Its probably due to you having more than one google map script rather than the actual positioning of the script reference? See if you're able to successfully concatenate them, like @dhaliman did for me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can include one link:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBSsKUzYG_Wz7u2qL6unHqfBOmvaZ0H1Mg&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Basically merging the url parameters in both the links.

Comment: I need to show three different maps on one page and getting error, How can I import multiple maps in one page

Comment: Is there a reason why this is needed? Or is this just recommended?

Comment: When used this method, API key will be public.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem that disturbed me for long time. My case was to combine initMap to load map and Google Places API to list autocomplete to the input search.

Here is my solution to this.

1. The function for autocomplete I've put inside the initMap()

> ```
> function activatePlacesSearch() {
>
> var input = document.getElementById('inputValue');
>     var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
> }
> activatePlacesSearch();
> ```

2. in index.html:

```
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
```

So best solution is to:

a) combine two scripts into one

b) place sensro functionality insite the initMap if possible.