# “You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page” Error

Tags: php, google-maps

I have seen [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44969698/you-have-included-the-google-maps-api-multiple-times-on-this-page-error) suggesting a solution to the issue i'm facing at the moment although not sure how to implement it since i'm using a code that is part of php system I recently purchased, not sure how to modify my code for it

This is how it runs on my code at the moment

```
array('file' => '', 'path' => 'https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?'.$api_key_str.'sensor=false&language=' . $this->option_arr['o_map_language'])
```

How should I apply the code so I would be able to run google maps more than once in a page?

Thanks!

Comment: we need more than that to determine the problem... it is impossible to know what is happening here

Comment: That is **one** of the multiple times the API is included.  Where is the other?  Remove one of them.

Comment: @geocodezip I need them both !

Comment: Why do you believe you need them both?  In general, you can only load the API once (the exceptions were API 2 & 3 in very specialized circumstances)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to implement the map more than once and you are calling the Maps Javascript API script tag. Please note that the Maps Javascript API script tag should only be called once and you can add multiple maps in your site by declaring multiple maps instantiation like:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
```

Here is a sample as well:

```js
var map;
var map1;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
  
  map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-1'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 45%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map-1 {
  height: 45%;
}
```

```html
<h3>
Map #1
</h3>
<div id="map"></div>
<h3>
Map #2
</h3>
<div id="map-1"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAj0aaMu_aY6xiDSWH0ac_4pqN_l-opwmI&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Hope this helps.