# Google maps - InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My code is as follows:

```
var mapLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(27, -83)
 var mapOptions = {
 zoom: 8,
 center: mapLatLng,
 draggable: true,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
 gestureHandling: ‘cooperative’,
 minZoom: 7
 }

 this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(‘map_canvas’), mapOptions);

 this.drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
 drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
 map: this.map
 )}
```

in my html I have

```
<div id =“map_canvas”></div>
```

I know what the issue is, but I’m not sure how to solve it. I need to use a utility class that imports the google maps api with the library of places. However, in another utility class I have to import the drawing and geometry libraries from google maps api.

I have to do it this way because the former includes components that I need for my application but the former doesn’t have the drawing and geometry libraries which I also need. I can’t edit the former utility class. If I could I would just add the drawing and geometry libraries to it.

The only way I can get this to work is to import the google maps api twice. The issue is that I’m getting this setMap error from the title. Is there anyway I can get around this issue while importing the google maps api twice?

Comment: Adding the API twice is not recommended. Maybe you should reevaluate the need to use that utility library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the Maps API twice will likely cause errors, such as this JS one:

> You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page.
>   This may cause unexpected errors.

E.g. see ["You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44969698/you-have-included-the-google-maps-api-multiple-times-on-this-page-error)

You should be able to modify your existing JavaScript API call to include the extra libraries. As in, call the API just once and include all of those libraries in the request like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places,drawing,geometry
```

Hope this helps!