# Angular google maps giving an error

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I am trying to get angular google maps to work, but I am encountering these errors.

> angular.js:88 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/modulerr?

The above error continues for about half a page.

> https://csi.gstatic.com/csi?v=2&s=mapsapi3&v3v=29.10&action=apiboot2&e=10_1_0,10_2_0&rt=main.31 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

**index.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
 <style>
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .angular-google-map-container {
        height: 100vh;
    }
</style>
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/
angular.min.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js">
</script>
<script src="./node_modules/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-
maps.js"></script>
<script src="./map.controller.js"></script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBL3uzNfWSpztGvmqhBLf-
gYdfdxrCSOQo">
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="gMap">
    <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom' aria-
    label="Google map">

        <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="marker in markers" coords="marker.coords" 
        options="marker.options" events="marker.events" idkey="marker.id">
            <ui-gmap-window>
                <div>{{marker.window.title}}</div>
            </ui-gmap-window>
        </ui-gmap-marker>

    </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**app and controller**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps']);

myApp.factory("Markers", function(){
  var Markers = [
  {
    "id": "0",
    "coords": {
    "latitude": "45.5200",
    "longitude": "-122.6819"
  },
  "window": {
    "title": "Portland, OR"
  }
},
{
  "id": "1",
  "coords": {
    "latitude": "40.7903",
    "longitude": "-73.9597"
  },
  "window" : {
    "title": "Manhattan New York, NY"
  }
}
];
return Markers;
});

myApp.controller("gMap",function($scope,Markers){
  $scope.map = { 
   center: { latitude: 39.8282, longitude: -98.5795 }, 
  zoom: 4 
 };
$scope.markers = Markers;
});
```

Can someone please help me solve this?

Comment: You are missing a module, which module it is should be present in the error URL that angular generates, which isnt clear in this case. You might wanna post the enitre error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct your `Markers factory` implementation, `factory` must return an object.

So change it like :

```
myApp.factory("Markers", function(){
  var Markers = [
  {
    "id": "0",
    "coords": {
    "latitude": "45.5200",
    "longitude": "-122.6819"
  },
  "window": {
    "title": "Portland, OR"
  }
},
{
  "id": "1",
  "coords": {
    "latitude": "40.7903",
    "longitude": "-73.9597"
  },
  "window" : {
    "title": "Manhattan New York, NY"
  }
}
];
return {
   markers: Markers
  };
});
```

Then in your `gMap controller`, consume factory array like:

```
$scope.markers = Markers.markers;
```

**Update:**

You also need to import `angular-simple-logger.js` library since it is dependecy of googlemap api. See this [fiidle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5nrf4eb/)

Comment: I tried what you said but I still get the same error :/ I dunno whatever code I try I am getting this huge injector.moduler error..I am completely lost on what to do

Comment: @kashifroshen : googlemap api has dependency on `angular-simple-logger.js` library as well, which also need to be imported. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5nrf4eb/) and I updated my answer.

Comment: You are a lifesaver man..Thanks a million..it is loading now..I have a question..When I include the google map api script tag with my api key it says "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors." Should I include it or is the script tags included enough?

Comment: I still can't upvote your answer..sorry about it..reputation is not enough xD

Comment: @kashifroshen:  you just need to include 1 script tag with all required parameters in one go. See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29930559/3455035) and now you can upvote as well... :)