# Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError - I do have it but it is not recognize

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have the google API key but the browser doesn't recognize that. You can go my site: [**`rodcurvelo.com`**](http://rodcurvelo.com), click contact and you will see the error.

The browser says also:

> **You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors**.

Here is my code:

```
         <div class="map-area" id="map-contact">
          <script async defer src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&ampsensor=false&ampkey=AIzaSyDwPJ1GDAq8GFIQmlMYyRFId7wRtQTFUF8"></script>
         </div>

       <div class="hidden map-contact-body">
        <div class="map-content">
          <h4 class="no-margin-top font-alt">Iam Here</h4>
          <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> <strong>Address:</strong> 8723 Bogor, West Java</p>
          <p><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i> <strong>Phone:</strong> 87-3898-221 </p>
          <p><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <strong>Email:</strong> someone@company.com</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--END MAP-->
      <!-- maps js -->
       <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script src="assets/plugins/jquery.ui.map.js"></script> 


      //theme.js
      //Run function When Document Ready
      $(document).ready(function() {
         initMap();

      });

          //Map
          function initMap() {
          $('#map-contact').gmap({
          'center': '27.867473, -82.637582',
          'zoom': 15,
           scrollwheel: false,
          'disableDefaultUI': false,
          'callback': function() {
          var self = this;
          self.addMarker({
           'position': this.get('map').getCenter(),
            icon: 'assets/theme/images/marker.png'
            }).click(function() {
            self.openInfoWindow({
            'content': $('.map-contact-body').html()
          }, this);
        });
       }
     });
    }
```

Comment: This is not a valid way to include the key: `&ampkey=AIzaSyDwPJ1GDAq8GFIQmlMYyRFId7wRtQTFUF8`, you are missing the `;` so it won't see the key.  It should be `&amp;key=AIzaSyDwPJ1GDAq8GFIQmlMYyRFId7wRtQTFUF8` or `&key=AIzaSyDwPJ1GDAq8GFIQmlMYyRFId7wRtQTFUF8`; and as  @Roee indicated, you are including it twice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixing "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930274/fixing-you-have-included-the-google-maps-api-multiple-times-on-this-page-this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're requiring Google Maps API twice;

`<script async defer src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&ampsensor=false&ampkey=AIzaSyDwPJ1GDAq8GFIQmlMYyRFId7wRtQTFUF8"></script>`

And: `<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"type="text/javascript"></script>`

Try joining them together (see this: [Fixing "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930274/fixing-you-have-included-the-google-maps-api-multiple-times-on-this-page-this))

Also, I'm not entirely sure about you're usage of async defer, as far as I know it's either `script async` or `script defer`, not both :)